# Wallch Doesn't work

Tags: desktop-background

I've installed `wallch` from both the apt, and the source from sourceforge, and both not working.

Simply adding an image to the queue and setting it as the background works, but both "Live Earth" and "Picture of the Day" features, won't work at all.

Any thoughts on why this can happen?

I'm using `Ubuntu 12.10` and `wallch 3.0`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please install the latest PPA that solves your problem:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:wallch/3+
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install wallch
```

For more information, please see https://bugs.launchpad.net/wallpaper-changer/+bug/1167911

Update:

The `ppa:wallch/wallch-daily` now is the one updated with any changes.

Answer (score 2):

Once I used Wallch, but I found out that Variety quite customable. Variety way to go. Hope it help. Read about Variety here, [Variety](http://peterlevi.com/variety/)

Answer (score 0):

When I had Wallch installed it would run but often a push was needed to get it started.

Let me recommend [Variety](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/variety/), it works perfectly well and the user can select multiple folders or various wallpaper websites.